# Why is JSLint complaining about my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jslint

```
{
   out = rogueArray[13];
   for (var arrayItem in vanWilder) 
   {
```

This is what I am told on JSLint:

```
Error:

Problem at line 52 character 18: Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.

for (var arrayItem in vanWilder)

Problem at line 52 character 18: Stopping. (30% scanned).

Implied global: requestOne 19,22,25,27, XMLHttpRequest 19, document 29, out 51

Unused variable: evilVariable 25 "onreadystatechange", redBull 25 "onreadystatechange", wildGoose 25 "onreadystatechange", monkeyWrench 25 "onreadystatechange"
```

How would I fix this?
If not the second error, the first one at least!

Comment: I believe you just need to place your variable definition `var arrayItem` at the top of it's current scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem at line 52 character 18: Move 'var' declarations to the top of the function.

Because JavaScript doesn't have block scope, and variable definitions are hoisted, Crockford recommends you place all variable definitions at the top of the scope.

> Implied global: requestOne 19,22,25,27, XMLHttpRequest 19, document 29, out 51

Because `out` doesn't have the `var` keyword to the left, it will be attached to `window`, essentially making it a global.

> Unused variable: evilVariable 25 "onreadystatechange", redBull 25 "onreadystatechange", wildGoose 25 "onreadystatechange", monkeyWrench 25 "onreadystatechange"

You must have defined a variable `evilVariable` somewhere and not used it.

---

Remember, Douglas Crockford is a smart man and his [JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) book is excellent, but take his word and JSLint as one man's recommendations and not the gospel. :)

Comment: So where exactly do I put the var?

Comment: @Amanda You should scope your variables like so: `var scopedVariable = 'Hello';`.

Comment: This is an older answer.  Javascript does now have block scope variable declarations with `let` and `const` and that would now be the recommended declaration for a `for` loop iteration variable `for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++)` or `for (const item of array)` in any circumstance where the loop variable doesn't need to be used outside the loop.